# How to retrive the recent post from facebook feed

Tags: php, facebook

I would like to retrieve recent post from my facebook account. I can able  to see the posts by the below  url

```
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=json&id=<myfbid>
```

The output coming as JSON format. But when I try to get the data using json decode in PHP. the data is not coming. Please let me know what is the issue.

Comment: Can you show us the code you are trying?

Answer (score 0):

```
$facebook->api(me/feed);
```

try this to get latest feed

are you using  json_decode ??

Comment: Yes, I am using the json_decode. Let me try this and get back you. thanks for your input